# Добавить в базу два списка в одну модель

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Есть два списка, одинаковой длины, релевантные двум полям в модели. Как добавить эти два списка синхронно в бд? Подозреваю что это можно как-то сделать за 1 запрос, ведь не делать же это тупо в цикле?

Answer (score 1):

```
model_object.field1.add(*list1)
model_object.field2.add(*list2)
```

конечно `field1` и `field2` должны быть `ManyToManyField`

Вообще надо читать [документацию](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/models/relations.html#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

Comment: Только с ManyToMany? Я делаю массовый импорт через админку обычных charset полей, добавил свою вьюху с textarea, распарсил регуляркой на два листа, можно в цикле я так понимаю .save() но мне кажеться это как-то топорно, вот и спрашиваю есть ли другой метод.
Нагуглил такую штуку https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create но это не для списков

Comment: Т.е. списки содержат не объекты моделей, а какие-то данные и эти данные поштучно нужно присвоить полям модели из первого списка к первому полю, а из второго второму? Если так то, в случае уже существующих записей к которым нужно добавлять данные списков, без цикла не обойтись (либо делать [RAW SQL запрос][1] с обновлением полей), а вот если записей ещё нет и их надо создать, то можно воспользоваться [bulk_create][2]

[1]:http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/topics/db/sql.html
[2]:http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/models/querysets.html#bulk-create